# What are the best delivery methods for handing off designs to developers?

Tags: user-interface, process, user-experience

I am working on a large and complex web application and am curious, from a developer's standpoint, about what the best methods are for handing over design to engineering in this type of environment. I'm curious about methods of delivery and their pros and cons.

Delivery methods I have used in the past (all of the methods below include detailed wireframes):

- Layered PSDs with Layer Comps for interactive states.
- A GUI Kit - a PSD of design elements that the developers create markup for and pull from to make the design match wireframes.
- A CSS Kit - an HTML page that includes CSS styles and layouts that developers can pull from to match the wireframes.

Please feel free to add your own methods to this list, your experience with these methods and what methods you prefer. I'd like to know what methods work in different cases as well (creating a new feature from scratch, updating an existing feature, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a similar project which involved delivery of UI widgets for the development team. Some of them had built-in interactivity, written in javascript.

We delivered each widget in a separate folder containing the following subfolders:

- Dist

  - img
  - js
  - css
- Source

  - img
  - js
  - css
- Test

The **Source folder** contains usually the non-minified versions of js and css source. Also if you use SASS or LESS for your css (and you should be using it for such a huge project), the /Source/CSS folder is the place to store your uncompiled css sources. Also here, in the img folder we usually have included the PSD files we've used to design the component

In the **Dist**(ribution) **folder** we shipped the compiled and minified css, the images used (when necessary) combined in sprites, and also the minified js code. Although you can prepare all these minified versions by yourself, it's faster if you automate the whole process with Grunt. You simply define a task that minifies js and css and creates the appropriate folder structure. All with a single press of a button (it's actually a command being executed).

The **Test folder** usually includes a html page that renders the component and provides instructions on how to test its different states or interactive features. This html page should always use the css and js files from the Dist folder. It's also a good practice to include a short read.me file describing the steps required to include the component into an existing page. Last but not least, if we're speaking about responsive layouts, it's also a good practice to provide here screenshots with the widget/component rendered in mobile browsers at various resolutions (ipad/iphone/android phone).

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear, but I'm not looking for literally how to pass files to a developer. I'm asking what formats or methods of delivery they prefer to receive the design in to make their job easier.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, it's clear now. I will edit my answer